# Why the first() method and slices works differently in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the model:

```
class PhotoAlbum(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, auto_created=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Album name')
    type = models.ForeignKey(AlbumType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Album type')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And i have this code:

```
print(PhotoAlbum.objects.all().first())
print(PhotoAlbum.objects.all()[:1].get())
```

it seemed to me that the same objects should be displayed, but different ones are returned.

What's going on, isn't it an identical design?

Comment: Can you share the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the queryset is not ordered then [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#first) orders the queryset by the primary key so:

```
from django.db import connection
Pet.objects.all().first()
print(connection.queries[-1]['sql'])
# SELECT ... FROM <table> ORDER BY <table>."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

But slicing the queryset performs no such default ordering.

```
from django.db import connection
Pet.objects.all()[:1].get()
print(connection.queries[-1]['sql'])
# SELECT ... FROM <table> ASC LIMIT 1
```